# Unable to close a QDialog from a QPushButton inside the dialog with a close action

Tags: qt, dialog

I searched for now two days but i didn't find any help regarding my issue to close a non modal dialog from a QPushButton inside that dialog.

The Dialog is called by a QMainWindow, everything works but i can't close the dialog by the button, only the cross mark is working, i don't understand why it's so tricky, as it's not modal, i don't wait for "accept" or "reject" statements, "close" or "done" are more fitted.

Here is my code to call the dialog :

```
void MainWindow::showSystraySettingsDialog()
{
    sDialog = new SystrayDialog(this);
    //sDialog.show();
    sDialog->setModal(false);
    sDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    sDialog->show();
    sDialog->raise();
    sDialog->activateWindow();
}
```

the "sDialog" member is a pointer declared in "MainWindow.h"

Here is the action called to close the dialog in my dialog code :
SystrayDialog.cpp :

```
void SystrayDialog::createActions()
{
    closeAction = new QAction(tr("&Close"),this);
    connect(closeAction, &QAction::triggered,this, &SystrayDialog::close);
}
```

the Close Button :

```
    closeButton = new QPushButton;
    closeButton->setText(QString(tr("&Close")));
    closeButton->addAction(closeAction);
```

I don't understand the needs of signals here, i am not waiting for any condition to close the window, this dialog won't pass any arguments or values to the maindow...

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting QAction using addAction() to QPushButton, the action will not trigger by clicking the QPushbutton. You may have to connect QPushButton click Signal to Qdialog close Slot which works perfect. 
Or You may have to Connect QPushButton Click() Signal to closeAction triggered Signal like below,
connect(closeButton,SIGNAL(clicked()), closeAction,SIGNAL(triggered()));

Comment: OK, perfect, i understand now why it doesn't work ... but it's weird that triggering an action setup into a QPushButton 'actions' pool is not linked to the clicked() event of the button...
I mark it as solvd, thanks once again !